# How to scrape a website based on response headers using requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to scrape https://www.foodhall.co.id/grand-indonesia/catalog .
I found the api https://api.foodhall.co.id/v1/catalog/productbycategoryv2 for the url above where the products are loaded from. I checked the response headers via inspect element and the returned response headers is as so:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 16 Jan 2023 03:07:59 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie: advanced-api=cigighcd1tcmdoj0eic643mogl; path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 2685
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=94
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

What do I have to notice for in the response headers so that I don't get an invalid authorization error.

Currently my code is as follows

```
import requests

payload={
    'store':'49',
    'category_id':'',
    'search':'',
    'filter':"",
    'tag':"",
    'lang':'ID',
    'page':'0'
}
headers={
    'Authorization': 'Bearer 17485f41ae19fbba0f4edf3241c9f033bb1af4e1c843789acfc9cf5136d443ea1673838475',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length': '57',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Host': 'api.foodhall.co.id',
    'Origin': 'https://www.foodhall.co.id',
    'Referer': 'https://www.foodhall.co.id/',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
reponse=requests.post('https://api.foodhall.co.id/v1/catalog/productbycategoryv2',json=payload,headers=headers)
```

The response json is returning a {'success': 0, 'message': 'invalid Authorization'}.I thought that the set cookie response needs an authorization, so my next step is to figure out how to get the authorization code I guess.

Can someone help me?

Comment: The usual way to do it is browse the website, while authenticated, with a browser having the Network developer tools activated, so you will see exactly what headers are sent, then you can copy that to your Python code.

Comment: Is that the same as the inspect element network? I tried passing the same headers but the response is that {'success': 0, 'message': 'invalid Authorization'}

Comment: I think so. Do you pass **exactly all the same** headers ?

Comment: yes everything is copied all the same